# Orientdb login fails all the sudden

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I've been using orientdb-2.2.19 for a while with no problem. After restarting my computer today the http://xxx.xxx.x.x:2480/studio/index.html#/ login page does not let me log into my database. The bin/server.sh command does not show any error:

```
 GRAPH DATABASE  
       ``        `.                                                          
                 ``                                          orientdb.com
                 `                                    
/hdd/orientdb-2.2.19
removing old pid file /hdd/orientdb-2.2.19/bin/orient.pid

2018-01-04 12:40:30:080 INFO  Loading configuration from: /hdd/orientdb-2.2.19/config/orientdb-server-config.xml... [OServerConfigurationLoaderXml]
2018-01-04 12:40:30:250 INFO  OrientDB Server v2.2.19 (build 1758205114667e967bba32d61adda4022bbad08e) is starting up... [OServer]
2018-01-04 12:40:30:253 INFO  Databases directory: /hdd/orientdb-2.2.19/databases [OServer]
2018-01-04 12:40:30:297 INFO  OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=11,969MB (heap=1,963MB direct=524,288MB os=15,980MB) [OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer]
2018-01-04 12:40:30:509 INFO  Listening binary connections on 0.0.0.0:2424 (protocol v.36, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2018-01-04 12:40:30:512 INFO  Listening http connections on 0.0.0.0:2480 (protocol v.10, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2018-01-04 12:40:30:519 INFO  Installing dynamic plugin 'orientdb-studio-2.2.19.zip'... [OServerPluginManager]
2018-01-04 12:40:30:521 INFO  ODefaultPasswordAuthenticator is active [ODefaultPasswordAuthenticator]
2018-01-04 12:40:30:522 INFO  OServerConfigAuthenticator is active [OServerConfigAuthenticator]
2018-01-04 12:40:30:523 INFO  OSystemUserAuthenticator is active [OSystemUserAuthenticator]
2018-01-04 12:40:30:537 INFO  Installed GREMLIN language v.2.6.0 - graph.pool.max=50 [OGraphServerHandler]
2018-01-04 12:40:30:537 INFO  [OVariableParser.resolveVariables] Error on resolving property: distributed [orientechnologies]
2018-01-04 12:40:30:540 WARNI Authenticated clients can execute any kind of code into the server by using the following allowed languages: [sql] [OServerSideScriptInterpreter]
2018-01-04 12:40:30:541 INFO  OrientDB Studio available at http://xxx.xxx.x.x:2480/studio/index.html [OServer]
2018-01-04 12:40:30:541 INFO  OrientDB Server is active v2.2.19 (build 1758205114667e967bba32d61adda4022bbad08e). [OServer]
```

I can log into the default "GreatfulDeadConcerts" database with the same username/password though. So I know I'm using the correct username and pass.

What could cause this problem?
On possible thing is that I copied the entire orientdb-2.2.19 folder from another directory into the one I'm using now. But this did not cause any problem for almost three weeks. So not sure if this is the real reason.

**Update:** 
As suggested, I setup a new user and password but the login still fails. This seems to be a more serious problem than just a login issue. 
I ran this command:

```
orientdb>CONNECT plocal:../databases/Test HUser HPass
```

which gave me the following error:

```
Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "public"
```

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko do you have any possible solution for this issue?

Comment: Check and/or modify the pass in the config file

Comment: But the pass in the config file is encrypted, how am i supposed to modify it? Can I just replace that long encrypted pass with something like "1234"?

Comment: Yes, you can, If you want to update it and keep encrypted, use SET SET SERVER USER <user-name> <user-password> <user-permissions>
 command in the console, see: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Set-Server-User.html

Comment: Here's what I did: orientdb> SET SERVER USER newUser newPass *, it showed: Server user 'HUser' set correctly, restarted the database, still no luck

Comment: Hi user1512681, have you try connect with admin?